# Javascript - Access JSON object array

Tags: javascript, json

I have some JSON that looks like so:

```
data
  row_234745
    enqitem
       cost : "75.34"
```

It is stored in a `data` variable.  I can access it in javascript like so:

```
console.log(data.data.row_234745.enqitem);
```

The problem is that row_234745 is variable.  How can I make it so that the console displays the cost value without specifying the row?

I've tried things like:

```
console.log(data.data[0].enqitem);
```

But having no luck.

Comment: Still not getting you. Can you dump `data` exactly as it is in your code in the question

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
let row = "row_234745";
data.data[row].enqitem
```

Answer (score 1):

Use bracket notation (`[]`) which allows properties/variables to be evaluated dynamically:

Try

```
var temp = 'row_234745';
console.log(data.data[temp].enqitem);
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have a look at the below example (executed on `Node REPL`) if it satisfies you needs.

> If it doesn't satisfy, let me know in comment.

```
> var row_234745 = "branch";
undefined
>
> var data = {
... data: {
..... branch: {
....... enqitem: {
......... cost: "75.34"
......... }
....... }
..... }
... }
undefined
>
> data.data[row_234745].enqitem
{ cost: '75.34' }
>
```